# How to execute a command on server using Expect

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, server, expect

I want to remotely delete a file/execute another script on my server. Manually this could be done by `ssh-login` -> `cd /path/` -> `rm somefiles` -> `. script.sh`

I want to automatic this process. So that when I execute `expect expectscript.sh port serverip user userpasswd`, the script would do the whole process for me.

So I write the following script. Things go smoothly till the `ssh-login` process finished. I don't know what is wrong with the last 3 lines of the code. Could someone help?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20
set port [lindex $argv 0]
set ip [lindex $argv 1]
set user [lindex $argv 2]
set password [lindex $argv 3]
spawn ssh "$user\@$ip" "-p" "$port"
expect "password:"
send "$password\r"
spawn "cd /etc/abcd/"
spawn "rm -f efg/*"
spawn ". somescriptinefg.sh"
```

Comment: I think maybe `send` not `spawn`. will reply if solved.

Comment: Since you already have ssh setup, why not directly run `ssh user@ip "cd /path && rm sometimes && ./script.sh"`. Why all the except business? If you don't have ssh set up for passswordless logins, you can use `sshpass`. Much more robust than expect which is a last resort.

Comment: In my case majorly because there are more than 1 servers and I want to run through the same process (with multiple steps) on them, by simply using ssh command, passwords will be asked for multiple times.

Comment: You can prevent the password query using a key pair or if you can't do that, you can, as I mentioned above, use sshpass. This can be looped over using a simple shell script. It will be much faster and more robust than an expect based solution.

Comment: I shall say the fact rather than something "nice". No, I am not fancy about using a "tool" while I can achieve the same result by some simple script. Also, 1. I won't use key pair because I have several "tempory server" that I would like to maintain. doing the key-pair thing could be a colossal waste of time. 2. script write by myself rather than a "tool", as stated before.

Comment: Your script is not simple. Sshing to a server and running a script there and can be done trivially using `sshpass` (if you prefer the unsafe password way) or using ssh directly if you can drop a pre generated key when you spin up new servers. As a demonstration, look at [this](https://pastebin.com/jRiHyDrx). The sshpass approach is 10 times faster and way more robust. I don't see any advantages to your approach nor do I see *not* writing a script as a waste of time.

Comment: OK. `sshpass` seems do not support ssh port other than 22. If there is a way to solve this problem, I will be more than willing to use it.

Comment: `sshpass` expects a command to run. You usually give an ssh pipeline there and that can change the port. So something like `sshpass -p s33kr3t ssh -p 5678 noufal@server`.

Comment: It worked, and it helped. Thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `spawn` to `send` solve the problem~

Literally,

`spawn` "Creates a new process by running a given program."

`send` "Sends string to the current process."

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the password is being sent with a spawn command rather than a send command. Additionally, ssh can be called with a specific command to run during the session, for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20
set port [lindex $argv 0]
set ip [lindex $argv 1]
set user [lindex $argv 2]
set password [lindex $argv 3]
spawn ssh $user@$ip -p $port "cd /etc/abcd/; rm -f efg/*; . somescriptinefg.sh"
expect "password:*"
send "$password\r"
expect eof
```

It might be worth configuring ssh keys for [passwordless access](https://linuxconfig.org/passwordless-ssh) instead. This would eliminate the need for an expect script and reduce the whole thing to a single line. If you really need to have an interactive ssh session, then a tool such as [sshpass](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) could be a less impractical alternative.

Comment: hmm, I sent the password with the `send` command, the login process seems alright. I solved the problem by modifying the `spawn` command in the last 3 lines to  `send`. But thank you anyway.